# Post Redirect Get Pattern using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm unable to redirect to my Get method after the Post method in the same controller as shown below..

My javascript code which initiates Post call..

```
$.ajax("home/myquery", {
    /*data: JSON.stringify(tmp1),*/
    data:  JSON.stringify({id:tmp1}),
    type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) { window.location.replace(window.location.host + '/MyController/MyReport/'+ result); },
    error: function (result) { alert("Error Saving") }
    });
```

My method in asp.net mvc controller which accesses the call..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyQuery(string id)
{  
//do some work here

    return return this.Content("abc");
}
```

The method to which it needs to redirect..

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MyReport(string model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can't redirect this way in ajax call return url as json and redirect from js in sucess function

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - ok have changed the code, still not working

Comment: ``window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MyReport","MyController")?model='+ result;``

Comment: If you intending to redirect if successful, then your should be using a standard submit, not ajax (and if there is an error, return the view)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're setting the expected return of "application/json", you should return from your controller this: `return JSON("abc")`